# How do I set up my HP LaserJet P2015 tray 3 to print my medical claim forms automatically? Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, printer

When I select the tray in printer options, I have to close my office software completely to change back to the other paper tray.

Comment: Which Office product are you using for the medical claim forms?

Comment: You shouldn't have to close Office to change which tray you are going to use to print a document.  Something doesn't sound right.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I think this will work:

Have a look at this article from HP:

[HP Printers - Creating Custom Paper Sizes | HP® Customer Support](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c03890386)

What you want to do is create a custom template or paper type/size unique to the medical claim forms, even if the paper is the same size and thickness used for other documents.

Then, you tell the printer that this new paper type is stored in tray 3.

Next, you make sure your medical forms are set up to use that particular type of paper. As long as the "Automatically select" option is enabled on the printer for which tray to use, it should correctly route the documents based on the "type" of paper expected. So, medical forms will use tray 3, and the rest of your documents should use whatever tray has standard paper.